# how to get byte array from camera preview in java android?

Tags: java, android, camera, preview

I'm a complete noob . I've managed to write and understand this code after reading this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html .
But now i want to get the byte array for preview and then convert it to bitmap .  But i want to do this in real time without be forced to save a picture file in storage . Please , help!
Here is my program code.

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String TAG = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.


    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        String TAG = null;
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)

    {
        // TODO: Implement this method

    }
};
```

}

And main activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{   private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview; 
int i;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);

    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
    preview.addView(mPreview);



} 
public static Camera getCameraInstance()
{
    Camera c = null;
    try
    {
        c = Camera.open();}
    catch (Exception e)
    { System.out.println("blamjjjh");}
    return c;
}
public void releasec(){
    mCamera.release();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{

    super.onStop();
    releasec();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed [in the Android Developer docs here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) (which you might have already read),  add an implementation of the `PictureCallback` interface (see the example below) to your Activity.  Also you can use `BitmapFactory` to then convert the byte array that gets passed back to a `Bitmap`.  Then you can use this as required.

NOTE: 
I would also read [the docs here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) on handling Bitmaps efficiently in relation to memory as you might get `OutOfMemory` errors if you're manipulating Bitmaps.

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

       //create a Bitmap from the byte array
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);

       //use your Bitmap
    }
};
```

You then need to pass this into the `takePicture()` method against your camera instance e.g.

```
// Add a listener to the Capture button
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get an image from the camera
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    }
);
```

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I think you don't understood what I want to do. I want to do some real-time processing directely on preview , without using a button for capturing a picture and then process it . I want to do the processing while the preview is displayed .  To be more precise I want to take a picture everytime the surface has been changed in preview .

Comment: Arh, ok my fault. That is certainly more complicated so will leave for another to answer unless I can think of an answer in the mean time.

Comment: Actually I've the same requirements as yours and I'm stuck right where you were 4 years ago.
If you have the solution, can you please post that?

Comment: Yes. I have solved it, I will post a solution in a short time. (I am unable to post it right now)

Comment: @Madalin did you post it in the meantime?

Comment: @Madalin, I'm having the same problem how did you solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063524/how-to-get-each-frame-data-using-camera2-api-in-android5-0-in-realtime  please check out this question for more clarifications