# Low FPS with Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am experiencing a low FPS rate with the new camera2 api. Specifically, 
despite choosing the highest FPS range (30,30) from

```
characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);
```

and setting it with

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, bestFPSRange);
```

I get much lower average rates for high image resolutions on both devices I have tested (Samsung S5 and Xperia Z3 Compact). Here is how I set up the `OnImageAvailableListener`:

```
int format = ImageFormat.YUV_420_888;
Size largest = map.getOutputSizes(format)[0];
Log.d("Images", "sizes: " + Arrays.toString(map.getOutputSizes(format)));
mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(), format,
        /* maxImages */50);
mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new OnImageAvailableListener() {

    private int  frames      = 0;
    private long initialTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        reader.acquireLatestImage().close();
        frames++;
        if ((frames % 30) == 0) {
            long currentTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
            long fps = Math.round(frames * 1e9 / (currentTime - initialTime));
            Log.d("Image", "frame# : " + frames + ", approximately " + fps + " fps");
            frames = 0;
            initialTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos();
        }
    }
}, mBackgroundHandler);
```

Basically, the if statement above is taking an average FPS every 30 samples. In practice, at the highest resolutions on both devices (1920x1080), I see fps ranges of 15-20 fps. Others online seem to indicate, however, that 30fps should be possible regardless of the resolution, and in fact, using the old deprecated camera API, I CAN get 30fps on both devices with the highest resolution. So what am I missing?

I already tried all of the combinations of TEMPLATE (e.g. TEMPLATE_PREVIEW) and format (e.g. ImageFormat.YUV_420_888). Which other knob am I forgetting to twist?

Comment: Just to check basic things, are you just using setRepeatingRequest() for the request?

Comment: Yes. Have you ever tried timing it this way? If you just look at the display on the screen, you would never know you aren't getting the full 30fps, so I wonder how many people are actually getting the full 30fps, and how many simply haven't timed it

Comment: Hmmm... I found a few other devices, a Huawei Mate S, a HTC One M9, and a LG G4. It turns out that the S5, Z3, Mate S, and M9 are considered LEGACY devices. Meanwhile, the G4 is a FULL device. With the FULL device, I am having no problems with the fps, and in fact it seems possible to do absolutely huge frames at 30fps with the G4. However, I get only about 15fps at 1080p on the other devices.

Comment: Is that behavior to be expected with LEGACY devices? What is very strange to me is that, using the deprecated camera API, I can easily get 30fps on those devices.

Comment: The frame rate shouldn't be that low - LEGACY mode does add some overhead, since it has to in effect run camera2 on top of the deprecated camera API, but it should not be that significant.

Comment: I was hoping that it would work with.legacy devices, but the fact that all legacy devices give just about the same fps, while the full device gives 30fps, seems to suggest to me that overhead IS the problem here. I will try to write up a blog post and put the test app in the play store so others can try later.

Comment: Hi I got same problem too, I recently switch from Camera1 API to Camera2 and FPS drops badly, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: No solution other than to use the old API if you have old phonea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S5 and Z3 Compact are classified as LEGACY devices. I tested this code on other LEGACY devices, including a

Samsung Galaxy S5

Xperia Z3 Compact

HTC One M9

Huawei Mate S

All of them returned low frame rates (approximately 15fps) at 1080p. One of the phones I found, an LG G4, support the FULL profile. On that device, I was able to get 30fps at even high frame sizes. So I strongly suspect that there is overhead in the camera2 api's wrapper that is causing this problem.

Comment: Hi @bremen_matt, I'm having similar issues with some devices of our customers. Do you know if there is a list with all those so-called LEGACY models? BTW, even if the device is using Android 9+ will it work as a LEGACY model?

Comment: I have never seen a list, but I believe that in 2020, almost all phones will be FULL devices.

Comment: As a quick check to see which level your device supports, you can try installing an app from the play store. There seem to be many apps which would quickly display that information, like this one (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airbeat.device.inspector&hl=en&gl=US).